# Run two services with the same public port

Tags: linux, web-server, http

Say I have `http://localhost:8080`
pointing to my Jenkins instance and `http://localhost:8081` pointing to my Jira instance, what do I need to do to acess my services like `http://localhost/jenkins` and `http://localhost/jira` using the default port 80? Is this possible in Ubuntu?

Comment: an apache with mod_proxy running on port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Config snippet for NGINX to run as a reverse proxy**

```
http {

  # Some standard NGINX config stuff goes here
  ...

  # Listen on port 80
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.awesome.domain.com;

    # Proxy /jenkins to localhost port 8080
    location /jenkins {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

    # Proxy /jira to localhost port 8081
    location /jira {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    }
  }
}
```

See the [NGINX](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) docs for more info.

**Config snippet for Apache to run as a reverse proxy**

```
# First load the reverse proxy modules
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

# Make sure we're listening on port 80    
Listen 80

# Define a default vHost
<VirtualHost *:80>

  # Standard vhost stuff goes here if required
  # Probably should have something to handle / requests at least
  ....

  # Reverse proxy for Jenkins
  ProxyPass /jenkins http://localhost:8080
  ProxyPassReverse /jenkins http://localhost:8080

  # Reverse proxy for Jira
  ProxyPass /jira http://localhost:8081
  ProxyPassReverse /jira http://localhost:8081

</VirtualHost>
```

See the [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) docs for more info

Comment: Note: Your module paths may be different on Ubuntu... and these configs will listen on 0.0.0.0 making the sites available outside the machine (I assumed that would be what you wanted, but I just noticed that you asked for http://localhost/jira and http://localhost/jenkins which are only accessible locally (loopback interface)

Answer (score 3):

You need a properly configured webserver capable of proxying (e.g. Apache, Nginx) listening on localhost:80).